# Unable to parse the value of an element from response in python?

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.Session()
content = s.get('https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/Default.aspx').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html5lib")
print("viewState = " + str(soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"]))
print("UserDet = " + str(soup.select_one("#SchSel_hidCoreUserDet")["value"]))
```

---

**Result :**

ViewState = qdwrf3rf

> KeyError : Value whoch means no value exists for userdet

But see the response when I manually login.The value for Userdet exists.[image]

Why is the error occuring during requests with python while no problem with manual login.?

Comment: looks like you have an extra single quote at the end of your string #SchSel_hidCoreUserDet'

Answer (score 0):

No, the element with `id="SchSel_hidCoreUserDet"` does not have a `value`. Here is what I see if I open this page in the browser:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SchSel$hidCoreUserDet" id="SchSel_hidCoreUserDet" value="">
```

The value is actually empty - it is the browser who adds the `value` attribute with an empty value.

And, here is what I see if printing the element found by `BeautifulSoup`:

```
<input id="SchSel_hidCoreUserDet" name="SchSel$hidCoreUserDet" type="hidden"/>
```

In both cases, the element does not have a value.

---

You might be previously logged in to this site and it might remember you through cookies or the local storage. Try inspecting the source of the page in an incognito window, or a browser which you have not used to log in to this site.

Comment: See 440 line [here](view-source:https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/).It is assigning the value

Comment: @anderson I see `hidCoreUserDet.value = "";` on line 440.

Comment: sorry see 453 line

Comment: @anderson yeah, and it would be executed only if there is the "last login data" available, see line 408. That's exactly my point. You've been logged in to this site before and that's why you see the value in the browser.

Comment: exactly..I have done the same.[here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/70f1da35722fbff1ff7f0383c505a546)

Comment: First I have sent GET request to the url it is sending during the manual .So USerDet value has to be assigned now.But not assigned

Comment: @anderson `requests` cannot execute javascript, it is not a browser - that could be the reason.

Comment: then what would be an alternative.?

Comment: @anderson well, the simplest approach would be to switch to browser automation with `selenium` stopping thinking in terms of GETs and POSTs and starting to think in terms of elements and browser actions.

Comment: okay.huge thanks ..Very well explained.no one has answerd me for this since very long time.Can you please clarify me further.I will post my doughts on this only.?